# Is there a .NET SDK for Adobe Photoshop/Illustrator/InDesign?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, image

I have a page on my site where a user can upload a Photoshop, Illustrator, or InDesign file.

It's for a print shop, and they need to do things like see which fonts are used in the file, check if the file contains spot colors, and other information like the dimensions, resolution, color space, etc.

Is there an SDK out there that I can download/buy for .NET where I can get this kind of information from an Adobe file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sadly, it looks like their SDK is C based (at least for photoshop). Check [this](http://forums.adobe.com/message/2973936?tstart=0) out.